# Constantly print volume of raw PCM audio stream to terminal as a number from 0 to 1?

Tags: c, linux, shell, rust, pcm

Currently, I am trying to read the volume / gain of a raw 16 bit PCM audio stream. Basically, I'd like to be able to pipe a stream into an executable and print a number in a range from 0 (no sound) to 1 (at volume limit / 0db from clipping) followed by a new line. This should continue only when manually cancelled or when the audio source exits. It does not need to be very acurate, nor do the values require being smoothed heavily (like an RMS value; although a bit of smoothing would probably be better than none at all). The problem is that I understand very little of how to work with raw PCM, and when I found the math, I realized that I currently do not posses the skills required to do something like this. So my question would be: Could someone who's more familiar with the matter provide me with a working example code that could do the behaviour described above, idealy with an explaination of what exactly is done?

The language isn't too important, although something fast like Rust, C, C++, etc. would be preferred.

Comment: See https://crates.io/search?q=pcm